# mongodb regex for different element of a list

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have a array of keywords and want to use use regex to find the documents that contain any of those keywords. so what I am using currently is this:

```
for (var idx=0;idx<tags_list.length;idx++){

db.ht_twitter.find({"tweettext": {$regex: ".*[^@]"+tags_list[idx]+".*"}}).forEach(function(x){db.homonyms.save(x)})
}
```

that means for every `tags_list` elements I have to call this query which is very inefficient .

What can I optimize my query?

Comment: you could try the `|` (OR) operator in your regex. For instance, you could store each key word in a string separated with `|`, like this : `KeyString="keyW1|keyW2|keyW3` then just try to match your regex  like this : `{$regex: ".*[^@]"+KeyString+".*"}`

Comment: If the valid comment here is not clear enough then perhaps you should show what you actually need to apply against. Just noting that any regex in MongoDB is not going to be terribly efficient unless you can actually anchor it to the start of the string. But one query is always better than `N` queries.

Comment: @Ploutox thanks for the input. seems really much more efficient. @Neil Lunn all I am trying to do is to find cases  where `@` sign is missing in before a user screen name.

Comment: @Moj Glad I could help. I'll post it as an answer so you can close your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try the `|` (OR) operator in your regex.

For instance, you could store each key word in a string separated with `|`, like this :

`KeyString="keyW1|keyW2|keyW3"`

Then just try to match your regex like this : `{$regex: ".*[^@]"+KeyString+".*"}`